# Transformar bytes a gb con python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Se que es un problema básico, pero estoy un poco estancado con esto.

Básicamente tengo el siguiente array que contiene tamaños en bytes.

```
tx = [4055242520253, 200560311974, 100465380275, 85448559614, 73906479933]
```

Y quiero pasar esos bytes a GB y solamente a GB, no a kb, tb, etc.

Tengo esta función que está casi funcionando como quiero, solo que llega un punto en donde los gb pasan a tb.

```
def convert_size(size_bytes):
   if size_bytes == 0:
       return "0B"
   size_name = ("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB")
   i = int(math.floor(math.log(size_bytes, 1024)))
   p = math.pow(1024, i)
   s = round(size_bytes / p, 2)
   return "%s %s" % (s, size_name[i])
for x in tx:
  print(convert_size(x))

#output del print
#3.69 TB
#186.79 GB
#93.57 GB
#79.58 GB
#68.83 GB
```

Comment: Esa función hace más de lo que quieres. ¿Es una función que no es tuya y quieres adaptar?

Comment: Sí, la función no es mía y me gustaría adaptarla o ver si existe otra forma de hacer lo que busco.

Comment: lo necesitas hacer de esa forma o puedes hacer la conversión de forma normal (ósea dividiendo)??

Comment: Divide cada elemento por 1024^3: `print(list(map(lambda x:x/(1024**3), tx)))`

Comment: @aeportugal muchas gracias por tu ayuda, es justo lo que necesitaba.